# Get event of dropdown change value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the event whenever my dropdown change its value

currently i'm using:

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    // doing some process here
}
```

but what I want is to get the event even when changing the value of the dropdown through jQuery. Lets say I do something like this:

```
$('#dropdown').val( someValue );
```

I also want to catch the code above on the change event.

Is there a way for jQuery to get this event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you change the value via jQuery, you can trigger the change event on that element with:

```
$('#dropdown').val( someValue ).change();
```

or

```
$('#dropdown').val( someValue ).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Stupid me. I never think about this. Thank exactly what I needed. 10mins before I can accept this.

Comment: For what the OP wants that "can" should be a "should" :)  Programatically changing the vlaue does not trigger any events.  By design.  Only user actions trigger such events automatically.  Add `.change()` as needed